# Why Doesn't the Loop Repeat?

Tags: c

My question is this: Given a sentence, delete only the last "`THE`" from that sentence if it starts with the word "`WE`", otherwise delete all "`THE`"s.

my code does not delete second `THE` after the first `THE`.
What's wrong?

```
int main(){

    char sent[100];
    int i;

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    gets(sent);

    if(sent[0] == 'w' && sent[1] == 'e'){
        for (i=2;i<strlen(sent);i++){
            if(sent[i] == 't' && sent[i+1] == 'h' && sent[i+2] == 'e' && sent[i+3] == ' '){
                while( i < strlen(sent)){
                sent[i] = sent[i+1];
                sent[i] = sent[i+2];
                sent[i] = sent[i+3];
                sent[i] = sent[i+4];
                i++;
            }
            printf("\n%s",sent);
            }

        }
    }
    else
        for (i=0;i<strlen(sent);i++){
            if(sent[i] == 't' && sent[i+1] == 'h' && sent[i+2] == 'e' && sent[i+3] == ' '){
                while( i < strlen(sent)){
                sent[i] = sent[i+1];
                sent[i] = sent[i+2];
                sent[i] = sent[i+3];
                sent[i] = sent[i+4];
                i++;
            }
            printf("\n%s",sent);
            }

        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `sent[i] = sent[i+4];` Is the actual result of all the four assignments and it causes UB, due to access out of bounds.

Comment: Never put `strlen` calls in a loop test.  It squares the runtime of the loop.  Call it *once*, outside the loop, and store the result in a variable.  Your code will run much faster.

Comment: @Bob__ `i+4` is probably not out of bounds because the condition above checks that we haven't reached the terminating `0` byte yet.

Comment: It won't fix your problem, but i'd highly recommend to replace `gets()` with `fgets()`. That's because at the moment you could enter a sentence with, say, 200 characters, and `gets()` would just overwrite anything that happens to be located behind your array in memory (possibly causing a segmentation fault).

Comment: @gerardh I got your point. There still is the problem that the buffer in the posted code is uninitialised, so, if the user enter a string shorter than 4 bytes, the result is indeterminate.

Comment: @Bob__ I don't see the problem. If the string is shorter, than 4 bytes, then there will be a `0` within the first few bytes. The checks to find `"we"` or `"the "` will stop at that 0 byte and no out of bounds access will happen and no access to the buffer behind the entered string.

Comment: If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and of course [some documentation of C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: **Never use `gets`** since it is obsolete and dangerous. At least use [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  First, it is missing the `#include` statements for the needed header files.  There are several other problems with the posted code.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding: `gets(sent);`  The function `gets()` has been depreciated for many years and completely removed from the C language (about) 2009.  Strongly suggest using `fgets()`  (read the MAN page for details as `fgets()` has a different parameter list

Comment: OT: regarding: `for (i=0;i<strlen(sent);i++){`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`

Comment: regarding: `if(sent[i] == 't' && sent[i+1] == 'h' && sent[i+2] == 'e' && sent[i+3] == ' '){`  What happens when the user capitalizes the first character of the sentence?  Answer, the `if()` statement fails.  Suggest including:: `ctype.h` and making use of `toupper()` or `tolower()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the inner loop to copy the remaining text:

```
   for (i=2;i<strlen(sent);i++){
        if(sent[i] == 't' && sent[i+1] == 'h' && sent[i+2] == 'e' && sent[i+3] == ' '){
            while( i < strlen(sent)){
            sent[i] = sent[i+1];
            sent[i] = sent[i+2];
            sent[i] = sent[i+3];
            sent[i] = sent[i+4];
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n%s",sent);
        }
    }
```

There are 2 main issues:

1. If you remove a word you must continue to search at the same location. After the loop iteration is done, the `i++` is executed, advancing to the next position. Therefore you need to negate that effect by adding a `i--;` in case you removed an occurance of `the`.
2. Your inner loop to copy the remaining text messes up your counter for the outer loop. After you copied the text, `i` points to the last char terminating your loop. You must use a separate counter.

... and some more issues:

3. Minor issue: 
   You have useless assignments in the copy loop. If you assign a series of values to `sent[i]` only the last one will have an effect afterwards.
4. Minor issue:
   Using `strlen` as loop condition causes lot of extra runtime. Only use it if necessary. For the inner loop simply check the length once and store it.
5. `gets` is evil. You should use `fgets` instead.

An updated version could look like this:

```
       size_t len = strlen(sent);  // Calculate limit only once
       for (i=2; i < len; i++) {
            if(sent[i] == 't' && sent[i+1] == 'h' && sent[i+2] == 'e' && sent[i+3] == ' ') {
                size_t j = i;
                while (j <= len-4) { // also copy the terminating 0 byte
                    sent[j] = sent[j+4];
                    j++;
                }
                printf("\n%s",sent);

                len -= 4;    // String was shortened
                i--;         // Check current position again.
            }
        }
```

Note:
You should also take into account that the last word could be `the` without an extra space...

You might also think about using standard C library functions like `strstr`...

Answer (score 0):

The error that terminates your loop on the first occurrence of the word `the` is that the inner `while` loop modifies the loop variable `i` of the outer `for` loop.

```
        for (i=0;i<strlen(sent);i++){
            if(sent[i] == 't' && sent[i+1] == 'h' && sent[i+2] == 'e' && sent[i+3] == ' '){
                /* after this loop i points to the end of the string */
                while( i < strlen(sent)){
                    sent[i] = sent[i+1];
                    sent[i] = sent[i+2];
                    sent[i] = sent[i+3];
                    sent[i] = sent[i+4];
                    i++;
                }
                printf("\n%s",sent);
            }
        }
```

So when the `while` loop has moved `i` to the end of the string, the outer `for` loop will terminate as well.

This problem can be fixed by using a separate variable for the inner loop.
I also tried to fix the out-of-bounds access and moved `strlen` out of the loop. (still incomplete, see below)

```
        /* the length is constant except when we remove "the " */
        size_t len = strlen(sent);
        for (i=0; i < len; i++){
            if(sent[i] == 't' && sent[i+1] == 'h' && sent[i+2] == 'e' && sent[i+3] == ' '){
                /* use separate variable for inner loop */
                int j = i;
                /* limit len-3 tp prevent sent[j+4] from reading past the NUL ('\0') character */
                while( j < len-3){
                    /* useless assignments to the same array element removed */
                    sent[j] = sent[j+4];
                    j++;
                }
                len -= 4; /* we removed 4 characters */
                printf("\n%s",sent);
            }
        }
```

This code has still the problem that it doesn't remove "the the " because the `for` loop won't check the same position again after removing "the ".

One option would be to decrement `i` after removing "the ". If the string starts with "the the " this would temporarily set `i` to `-1`. It will be incremented again by the `for` statement.

I prefer to increment `i` only if "the " was **not** found.
That's why I move the `i++` from the `for` statement into the loop body.

```
        /* the length is constant except when we remove "the " */
        int len = strlen(sent);
        for (i=0; i < len; /* no i++ here */){
            if(sent[i] == 't' && sent[i+1] == 'h' && sent[i+2] == 'e' && sent[i+3] == ' '){
                /* use separate variable for inner loop */
                int j = i;
                /* limit len-3 tp prevent sent[j+4] from reading past the NUL ('\0') character */
                while( j < len-3){
                    /* useless assignments to the same array element removed */
                    sent[j] = sent[j+4];
                    j++;
                }
                len -= 4; /* we removed 4 characters */
                printf("\n%s",sent);
            } else {
                /* advance to the next character only if we didn't just remove "the " */
                i++;
            }
        }
```

The `while` loop can also be written as a `for` loop.

```
        /* the length is constant except when we remove "the " */
        int len = strlen(sent);
        for (i=0; i < len; /* no i++ here */){
            if(sent[i] == 't' && sent[i+1] == 'h' && sent[i+2] == 'e' && sent[i+3] == ' '){
                /* use separate variable for inner loop */
                /* limit len-3 tp prevent sent[j+4] from reading past the NUL ('\0') character */
                for(int j = i; j < len-3; j++){
                    /* useless assignments to the same array element removed */
                    sent[j] = sent[j+4];
                }
                len -= 4; /* we removed 4 characters */
                printf("\n%s",sent);
            } else {
                /* advance to the next character only if we didn't just remove "the " */
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Note: You can write the loops in various different ways, so there are other valid solutions, as you can see from the comments.

Comment: Also with limit `len` there will be no access to memory behind the `0` byte because the comparison will already fail at that `0` byte and no further bytes will be checked.

Comment: The inner loop does not copy the terminating byte and you won't detect `"the the "` properly.

Comment: @Gerhardh Both fixed now.

Comment: Nitpick: `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: So, proposing to rewrite this`int i; int len = strlen(sent); for (i = 0; ...` to look like `for (size_t i=0, len = strlen(sent); ...`.

Comment: Also this `int j = i; while( j < len-3) { sent[j] = sent[j+4]; j++; }` would be a perfectly clean foor-loop: `for (size_t j = i; j < len-3, ++j) { sent[j] = sent[j+4]; }`